# installing traceability plugin for redmine v1.1.3 (rake aborted! stack level too deep error)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, plugins, redmine, redmine-plugins

I installed redmine v1.1.3 and am using sqlite. It works fine but i am unable to complete traceability plugin installation.

I have downloaded traceability and placed it into `C:\redmine-1.1.3\vendor\plugins`.

```
set RAILS_ENV=production
```

rake db:migrate command fails

```
C:\redmine-1.1.3>rake db:migrate --trace
(in C:/redmine-1.1.3)
** Invoke db:migrate (first_time)
** Invoke environment (first_time)
** Execute environment
rake aborted!
stack level too deep
C:/redmine-1.1.3/lib/redmine/menu_manager.rb:28:in `old_initilize'
C:/redmine-1.1.3/lib/redmine/menu_manager.rb:28:in `old_initilize'
C:/redmine-1.1.3/lib/redmine/menu_manager.rb:28:in `initialize'
C:/redmine-1.1.3/lib/redmine/menu_manager.rb:314:in `new'
C:/redmine-1.1.3/lib/redmine/menu_manager.rb:314:in `initialize'
C:/redmine-1.1.3/lib/redmine/menu_manager.rb:299:in `new'
C:/redmine-1.1.3/lib/redmine/menu_manager.rb:299:in `map'
C:/redmine-1.1.3/lib/redmine.rb:148
C:/Ruby187/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:31:in `gem_original_require'
C:/Ruby187/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:31:in `require'
C:/redmine-1.1.3/vendor/rails/activesupport/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:158:in `require'
C:/redmine-1.1.3/config/initializers/30-redmine.rb:3
C:/redmine-1.1.3/vendor/rails/activesupport/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:147:in `load_without_new_constant_marking'
C:/redmine-1.1.3/vendor/rails/activesupport/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:147:in `load'
C:/redmine-1.1.3/config/../vendor/rails/railties/lib/initializer.rb:622:in `load_application_initializers'
C:/redmine-1.1.3/config/../vendor/rails/railties/lib/initializer.rb:621:in `each'
C:/redmine-1.1.3/config/../vendor/rails/railties/lib/initializer.rb:621:in `load_application_initializers'
C:/redmine-1.1.3/config/../vendor/rails/railties/lib/initializer.rb:176:in `process'
C:/redmine-1.1.3/config/../vendor/rails/railties/lib/initializer.rb:113:in `send'
C:/redmine-1.1.3/config/../vendor/rails/railties/lib/initializer.rb:113:in `run'

C:/redmine-1.1.3/config/environment.rb:31
C:/Ruby187/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:31:in `gem_original_require'
C:/Ruby187/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:31:in `require'
C:/redmine-1.1.3/vendor/rails/activesupport/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:156:in `require'
C:/redmine-1.1.3/vendor/rails/activesupport/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:521:in `new_constants_in'
C:/redmine-1.1.3/vendor/rails/activesupport/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:156:in `require'
C:/redmine-1.1.3/vendor/rails/railties/lib/tasks/misc.rake:4
C:/Ruby187/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:636:in `call'
C:/Ruby187/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:636:in `execute'
C:/Ruby187/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:631:in `each'
C:/Ruby187/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:631:in `execute'
C:/Ruby187/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:597:in `invoke_with_call_chain'
C:/Ruby187/lib/ruby/1.8/monitor.rb:242:in `synchronize'
C:/Ruby187/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:590:in `invoke_with_call_chain'
C:/Ruby187/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:607:in `invoke_prerequisites'
C:/Ruby187/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:604:in `each'
C:/Ruby187/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:604:in `invoke_prerequisites'
C:/Ruby187/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:596:in `invoke_with_call_chain'
C:/Ruby187/lib/ruby/1.8/monitor.rb:242:in `synchronize'
C:/Ruby187/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:590:in `invoke_with_call_chain'
C:/Ruby187/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:583:in `invoke'
C:/Ruby187/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:2051:in `invoke_task'
C:/Ruby187/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:2029:in `top_level'
C:/Ruby187/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:2029:in `each'
C:/Ruby187/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:2029:in `top_level'
C:/Ruby187/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:2068:in `standard_exception_handling'
C:/Ruby187/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:2023:in `top_level'
C:/Ruby187/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:2001:in `run'
C:/Ruby187/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:2068:in `standard_exception_handling'
C:/Ruby187/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:1998:in `run'
C:/Ruby187/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/bin/rake:31
C:/Ruby187/bin/rake:19:in `load'
C:/Ruby187/bin/rake:19
```

I am using Windows XP and

```
C:\redmine-1.1.3>ruby -v
ruby 1.8.7 (2010-08-16 patchlevel 302) [i386-mingw32]

C:\redmine-1.1.3>gem list

*** LOCAL GEMS ***

actionmailer (2.3.5)
actionpack (2.3.5)
activerecord (2.3.5)
activeresource (2.3.5)
activesupport (2.3.5)
i18n (0.4.2)
mysql (2.8.1 x86-mingw32)
rack (1.0.1)
rails (2.3.5)
rake (0.8.7)
sqlite3 (1.3.3 x86-mingw32)
```

I get this error on both Ubuntu with MySQL and Windows XP with MySQL. On Ubuntu I changed the stack size to unlimited for "stack level too deep" error but nothing changes.

Comment: Version 1.2.0 has now been released: http://www.redmine.org/projects/redmine/wiki/Changelog#120-2011-05-30. Can you try that instead?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of following the [plug-in installation](http://www.redmine.org/projects/redmine/wiki/Plugins) I tried below code and it works.

```
RAILS_ENV=production rake db:migrate
```